# Laravel Gallery function: Return img with desc: Error: Undefined variable: desc

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a PHP gallery with a `img` and a `desc` field.
The `img` field stores the url of the image.
The `desc` field provides a short explanation of the image.

This is my function to grab the data from my db.

```
 public function getGallery()
    {
        $images = array();

        foreach ($this->model->image->slice(0,36) as $img)
        {
            //if we've got images web url we'll use 
            //it to hotlink image
            if ($img->web)
            {
                $images[] = $img->web;
                $desc[] = $img->desc;
            }

            //otherwise we will use image that we downloaded locally.
            elseif ($img->local)
            {
                $images[] = $img->local;
                $desc[] = $img->desc;
            }
        }

        $count = count($images);

        //repeat images if we have less then 6
        if ($count < 36 && ! empty($images))
        {
            $duplicates = array_fill(0, 36 - $count, head($images));    
            $images = array_merge($images, $duplicates);
        }

        return (isset($images, $desc) ? $images : null);
    }
```

This is my Blade View

```
<div id="links">

 @foreach(array_slice($data->getGallery(), 0, 36) as $k => $img)

  <a href="{{ asset(Helpers::original($img)) }}" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6 image-col" data-gallery>
    <img src="{{{ Helpers::thumb($img) }}}" data-num="{{ $k }}" data-original="{{ Helpers::original(asset($img)) }}" alt="{{ 'Still of ' . $data->getTitle() }}" class="img-responsive pull-left thumb lightbox">
  </a>
 <figcaption title="{{{ $desc }}}" ></figcaption>
 @endforeach
```

I keep receiving 
Undefined variable: desc

Comment: Your `getGallery` function doesn't appear to return `$desc` in any way. It's constructed then discarded.

Comment: return (isset($images, $desc) ? $images : null); is this how I return it?

Comment: No, that's not returning $desc at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to keep things the way they are you can change your function to:

```
public function getGallery(&$desc)
{
    .... 
}
```

And your view to

```
@foreach(array_slice($data->getGallery($desc), 0, 36) as $k => $img)
   ...
@endforeach
```

But you would have to make sure you always get a value for them inside your getGallery() function.

---

Possibly you could change things a little bit in your structure to make your Controller pass this data to your view:

```
<?php

class MyController extends Controller {

    public function show() 
    {
        $gallery = ...; // retrieve your gallery model or repository here
        $data = $this->repository->model->getGallery(); /// run your getGallery method

        return View::make('gallery')->with('gallery', $gallery)->with('data', $data);
    }

}
```

And your gallery would have to return:

```
public function getGallery()
{
    ...

    return array(
                    'images' => isset($images, $desc) ? $images : null,
                    'desc' => $desc
                );
}
```

And your view would have to change to:

```
@foreach(array_slice($data['images'], 0, 36) as $k => $img)
    <a href="{{ asset(Helpers::original($img)) }}" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6 image-col" data-gallery>
    <img src="{{{ Helpers::thumb($img) }}}" data-num="{{ $k }}" data-original="{{ Helpers::original(asset($img)) }}" alt="{{ 'Still of ' . $gallery->getTitle() }}" class="img-responsive pull-left thumb lightbox">
    </a>
    <figcaption title="{{{ $data['desc'][$k] }}}" ></figcaption>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hi I changed my code to include (&$desc)

But my generated php doesn't return anything from the desc field
          all my 
     <figcaption title="" ></figcaption>
            are empty even though I have data for those `desc` fields in my db next to the `img` fields

Comment: I just added a better answer. Your view should not do this kind of work, it is supposed to be dumb and just receive data to show to your users.

Comment: Hi the problem is my gallery view is a TAB from within another view that describes the real estate property.    

<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="description">
        @include('Titles.Themes.Tabs.Description')
      </div>
      
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="gallery">
        @include('Titles.Themes.Tabs.Gallery')
      </div>
      
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="cast">
        @include('Titles.Themes.Tabs.Cast')
      </div>

Comment: Still, if you build all of your data and pass it to your main view, you'll have access to them in the included ones.